# Using invokeVerb for an array in VBScript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I found a script for install fonts and I edited it to install some fonts (array of fonts) alongside but it doesn't run. This line raises an error:

```
array.InvokeVerb("Install")
```

It seems to replace `InvokeVerb` with another function but I dont know!

Can some one help me?

My script:

```
Option Explicit
'Installing multiple Fonts in Windows 7

Dim objShell, objFSO, wshShell
Dim strFontSourcePath, objFolder, objFont, objNameSpace, objFile
Dim array : Set array = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

strFontSourcePath = "C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\new_Software\Fonts"

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFontSourcePath) Then
  Set objNameSpace = objShell.Namespace(strFontSourcePath)
  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFontSourcePath)

  For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase(Right(objFile,4)) = ".ttf" Or LCase(Right(objFile,4)) = ".otf" Then
      array.Add objNameSpace.ParseName(objFile.Name)
    End If
  Next
  array.InvokeVerb("Install")
Else
  WScript.Echo "Font Source Path does not exists"
End If
```

Comment: You need to do the `InvokeVerb` in the `For ... Next` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` objects don't have an `InvokeVerb` method, and VBScript doesn't provide [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) like PowerShell does (which would allow the interpreter to invoke the method on the array items rahter than the array itself).

As [ACatInLove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195780/using-invokeverb-for-an-array-in-vbscript#comment85435752_49195780) already mentioned you need to use a `For Each` loop to enumerate the array elements and invoke the method on each element:

```
For Each el In array
  el.InvokeVerb("install")
Next
```